# Pandas add variable as column and correspond to original table (but they have different length)

Tags: python, pandas

What I ask is kind of complicated so as the title. I made this example up to show you my question. Here is the sample table:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Number': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'Col1':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']})
```

[image]

Next step is to extract df['Number'] and run iteration for some reason. `number= [i*i for i in df['Number']]` the output is `[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]`

Now I have a variable 'number' which is a list.

Now the key step is I have to regroup this list. let's say number number is less than 40

```
number1 = [i for i in number if i < 40]
number2 = [i for i in number if i > 40]
```

OK, the key step I want is to add number1 and number2 to df, but the expected final output is like this:

[image]

That is, add a new column 'Type' and these two new variables have to match the index and the content is 'number1' and 'number2', but not '1,4,9...81'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with `boolean mask`:

```
print (df.Number.pow(2) < 40)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
Name: Number, dtype: bool

df['Type'] = np.where(df.Number.pow(2) < 40, 'number1', 'number2')
#same as
#df['Type'] = np.where(df.Number ** 2 < 40, 'number1', 'number2')
#another solution
#df['Type'] = np.where(df.Number.pow(2).lt(40), 'number1', 'number2')
print (df)
  Col1  Number     Type
0    a       1  number1
1    b       2  number1
2    c       3  number1
3    d       4  number1
4    e       5  number1
5    f       6  number1
6    g       7  number2
7    h       8  number2
8    i       9  number2
```

**Timings** - `numpy.where` is fastest:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Number': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'Col1':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']})
#[9000 rows x 5 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

df['Type'] = np.where(df.Number.pow(2).lt(40), 'number1', 'number2')

df['Type1'] = 'number' + (1 + ((df.Number**2)>40).astype(int)).astype(str)

# Rule to produce new values
def f(row):
    if row['Number']**2 > 40:
        val = 'Number2'
    else:
        val = 'Number1'
    return val

df['Type2'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)

#print (df)
```

---

```
In [218]: %timeit df['Type'] = np.where(df.Number.pow(2).lt(40), 'number1', 'number2')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.63 ms per loop

In [219]: %timeit df['Type1'] = 'number' + (1 + ((df.Number**2)>40).astype(int)).astype(str)
100 loops, best of 3: 13.5 ms per loop

In [220]: %timeit df['Type2'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 127 ms per loop
```

EDIT:

I create helper columns for better understanding comparing:

```
df['pow'] = df.Number.pow(2)
df['comaping val'] = 40
df['val'] = df.Number.pow(2).lt(40)
print (df)
  Col1  Number  pow  comaping val    val
0    a       1    1            40   True
1    b       2    4            40   True
2    c       3    9            40   True
3    d       4   16            40   True
4    e       5   25            40   True
5    f       6   36            40   True
6    g       7   49            40  False
7    h       8   64            40  False
8    i       9   81            40  False
```

Comment: I like your answer for this question. I would also like to ask when I extract 'number = df['Number']' and type 'number', it has two columns and one of them is the index. However, for 'number= [i*i for i in df['Number']]', the output is '[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]'. Where is the index?

Comment: You create list, but in my solution compare with `columns` - `Series`. I try add it to my answer, I hope now it is more clear. 
If not, let me know, I try explain more.

Comment: Is solution compare columns `pow` with `comaping val` and output is another column(`Series`) with `True, `False`.

Comment: Hi I still want to know if in a case I have to create list. Is there a method to do the same thing? (For example, to process strings, and you can't simply apply mathematical functions)

Comment: I think in pandas is better works with Series, what is faster as lists in larger df. Also for strings is possible use [string functions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here is my creative approach:

**Data:**

```
In [23]: df
Out[23]:
  Col1  Number
0    a       1
1    b       2
2    c       3
3    d       4
4    e       5
5    f       6
6    g       7
7    h       8
8    i       9
```

**Solution:**

```
In [24]: df['Type'] = 'number' + (1 + ((df.Number**2)>40).astype(int)).astype(str)
```

**Result:**

```
In [25]: df
Out[25]:
  Col1  Number     Type
0    a       1  number1
1    b       2  number1
2    c       3  number1
3    d       4  number1
4    e       5  number1
5    f       6  number1
6    g       7  number2
7    h       8  number2
8    i       9  number2
```

**Explanation:**

```
In [29]: ((df.Number**2)>40).astype(int)
Out[29]:
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    1
7    1
8    1
Name: Number, dtype: int32

In [30]: 1 + ((df.Number**2)>40).astype(int)
Out[30]:
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    2
7    2
8    2
Name: Number, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 1):

Make custom function and then use it in  `pandas.apply`

```
import pandas as pd

# Rule to produce new values
def f(row):
    if row['Number']**2 > 40:
        val = 'Number2'
    else:
        val = 'Number1'
    return val

df = pd.DataFrame({'Number': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'Col1':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']})

# Apply the function to construct new column
df['Type'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df)
```

Output:

```
 Col1  Number     Type
0    a       1  Number1
1    b       2  Number1
2    c       3  Number1
3    d       4  Number1
4    e       5  Number1
5    f       6  Number1
6    g       7  Number2
7    h       8  Number2
8    i       9  Number2
```